# Replacement for Hoefler Text

Tags: fonts, print-design

I have a resume that was designed on a Mac, which came with **Hoefler Text** pre-installed. I no longer have access to the Mac, but I need to edit the resume (done in Open Office Draw). It's not really an option to purchase the font.

Can anyone suggest a good alternative to **Hoefler Text** (read: looks as similar as possible)?  This resume took quite a while to design and I'm not really that keen on redoing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any flavour of Garamond should be fairly close.

Comment: I'll second that. Adobe Garamond in particular might have extra weights and characters you might need.

Answer (score 0):

I just type Hoefler into the font box and a message box comes up that tells me it is not available but do I want to use it anyway.  I click yes, and wala....document is now Hoefler

Comment: Welcome to GD.  That might work if you were to distribute the document to another machine that has Hoefler installed, but you could not do anything meaningful with it on your own machine (such as prepare it as a PDF for distribution).